# Leaflet rotate zoom issue

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, leaflet

I am using [leaflet rotate](https://github.com/va2ron1/Leaflet/) in a project and am having an issue with polygons and lines on zoom. [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmVWMy)

```
<script src="js/leaflet.rotate.js"></script>
<link href="css/leaflet.rotate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="mapID"></div>
<script>
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
}).addTo(mymap);

var polygon = L.polygon([
    [51.509, -0.08],
    [51.503, -0.06],
    [51.51, -0.047]
]).addTo(mymap);
</script>
```

I thought it was a conflict with my own code but have thrown together the above example using the leaflet polygon example and "Leaflet Rotate" JS and CSS and still get the issue.

I am pretty sure it is a CSS issue but am not sure where to even start.

On desktop the polygons move on zoom then snap back in place once zooming is finished but on mobile devices it is even worse as the polygons don't always snap back to the correct locations.

Any help would be very much appreciated. I did put an issue in the github repo but have had no response as of yet from the developer, if i am able to get a solution to work i will submit a pull request for the fix.

Comment: what is leaflet.rotate.js ? Could you try the newest version leaflet?

Comment: Leaflet.rotate is a fork of leaflet that allows the map to be rotated, this is not possible with leaflet without modifications.